# Counting Inversions In An Array - Special Case

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Inversion Count for an array indicates – how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If array is already sorted then inversion count is 0. If array is sorted in reverse order that inversion count is the maximum. 
Formally speaking, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j Example:
The sequence 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 has three inversions (2, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3).

Now, there are various algorithms to solve this in O(n log n).

There is a special case where the array only has 3 types of elements - 1, 2 and 3. Now, is it possible to count the inversions in O(n) ?

Eg 1,1,3,2,3,1,3

Comment: ankitG: google for dutch national flag problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. Just take 3 integers `a,b,c` where `a` is number of 1's encountered till now, `b` is number of 2's encountered till now and `c` is number of 3's encountered till now. Given this follow the algorithm below ( I assume numbers are given in array `arr` and the size is `n`, with 1 based indexing, also following is just a pseudocode )

```
    no_of_inv = 0
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    for i from 1 to n:
       if arr[i] == 1:
          no_of_inv = no_of_inv + b + c 
          a++
       else if arr[i] == 2:
          no_of_inv = no_of_inv + c
          b++
       else:
          c++
```

Answer (score 1):

(This algorithm is extremely similar to Sasha's. I just wanted to provide an explanation as well.)

Every inversion `(i, j)` satisfies `0 ≤ i < j < n`. Let's define `S[j]` to be the number of inversions of the form `(i, j)`; that is, `S[j]` is the number of times `A[i] > A[j]` for `0 ≤ i < j`. Then the total number of inversions is `T = S[0] + S[1] + … + S[n - 1]`.

Let `C[x][j]` be the number of times `A[i] > x` for `0 ≤ i < j`. Then `S[j] = C[A[j]][j]` for all `j`. If we can compute the `3n` values `C[x][j]` in linear time, then we can compute `S` in linear time.

Here is some Python code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3])
>>> C = {x: np.cumsum(A > x) for x in np.unique(A)}
>>> T = sum(C[A[j]][j] for j in range(len(A)))
>>> print T
4
```

This could be made more efficient—although not in asmpytotic terms—by not storing all `C` values at once. The algorithm really only needs a single pass through the array. I have chosen to present it this way because it is most concise.